# Replace characters using Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Hi I have a requirement to replace certain number of characters in a string with Regular expression. I have tried (to replace 1st 3 characters- can be numbers alphabets or anything in the string):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\d+\]{3}");
name = regex.Replace(name, "%");
```

But its not working; i have tried various options but unable to get the desired output. Need help! Thanks!

Comment: First three chars can be matches with `^.{3}`. Why not use `$"%%%{s.Substring(2)}"`?

Comment: Why do you use a regex for that?

Comment: It need not necessarily be first 3 characters always. That was an example; the characters can be anywhere or user can use any regular expression to replace characters in the string!

Comment: Then it sounds like a classic case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): you are asking how to complete the solution you decided on, without explaining what the underlying problem is. If you explain in full why you need to replace the first 3 characters sometimes, then we may be able to help you find a better solution than RegEx.